# Regex Binary Pattern Search in PHP

Tags: php, regex, binary-search, binary-data

I am trying to find and replace binary values in strings:

```
$str = '('.chr(0x00).chr(0x91).')' ;
$str = preg_replace("/\x00\x09/",'-',$str) ;
```

But I am getting **"Warning: preg_replace(): Null byte in regex"** error message.

How to work on binary values in Regex/PHP?

Comment: What do you mean by *binary* here?

Comment: Try `$str = preg_replace("/\x{00}\x{09}/",'-',$str) ;`

Comment: Why are you using a regexp instead of `str_replace()`?

Comment: I suspect the underlying regexp engine uses C-style strings, and C uses a null byte as the string delimiter. So it can't handle embedded nulls.

Comment: Or try single quotes around your pattern...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is because you are using double quotes `"` around your regex pattern, which make the php engine parse the chars `\x00` and `\x09`.

If you use single quotes instead, it will work:

```
$str = '(' . chr(0x00) . chr(0x91) . ')' ;
$str = preg_replace('/\x00\x09/', '-', $str) ;
```

But your regex seems also not to be correct, if I understood your question correctly. If you want to replace the chars `\x00` and `\x91` with a dash `-`, you must put them into brackets `[]`:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[\x00\x91]/', '-', $str) ;
```

Comment: Came across this error while allowing dynamic regex "match" strings. Wasn't sure of a fix until I came across this answer. Combining the above into this worked great for me!
`$matchString = str_replace(chr(0), '\x00', $matchString);`

Comment: Worked fro me.  Thank you!